# How to add a title for button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

My base code :

```
<button class="puple margin-right" type="button" onclick="setPasswordForm()" title="<?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?>" class="button"><span id="change_password_text"><?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?></span></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
    function setPasswordForm(){
        var arg = $('change_password').value;   

        if(arg == 0){
            $('current_password').up(3).show();
            $('current_password').addClassName('required-entry');
            $('password').addClassName('required-entry');
            $('confirmation').addClassName('required-entry');
            $('change_password').setValue('1');
            $('change_password_text').update('<?php echo $this->__('Cancel Change Password') ?>');            
        }else{
            $('current_password').up(3).hide();
            $('current_password').removeClassName('required-entry');
            $('password').removeClassName('required-entry');
            $('confirmation').removeClassName('required-entry');
            $('change_password').setValue('0');
            $('change_password_text').update('<?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?>');
        }
    }
    <?php if($this->getCustomer()->getChangePassword()): ?>
        setPasswordForm();
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I have a button "change password", and it will be change to "cancel change password" when a form "change password" have been displayed.
How to add a title for button "Cancel change password"?
Any answer ???

Comment: is it a normal <input type="button"> or is it jquery button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change these lines

`$('change_password_text').update('<?php echo $this->__('Cancel Change Password') ?>');`

to

`$('#change_password_text').text('Cancel Change Password');`

Same goes for the `else` statement.

Note: you are missing a `#` to target the `change_password_text` id.

Comment: My pleasure @KooreeLưu!  If either of these answers answered the question, consider clicking the checkmark beside one of them to let others know it is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a variable $button_title in your program logic first.

```
<button><?php echo $button_title; ?></button>
```

If you seek for a client-side ( JavaScript-based ) solution , here it is:

```
<button id="submit_btn"></button>
```

in JavaScript:

```
$('submit_btn').innerHTML = your_button_title_variable_set_in_javascript;
```

**UPDATE:** About assigning PHP variable to JavaScript variable:

in JavaScript:

```
var your_button_title_variable_set_in_javascript = '<?php echo $button_title; ?>';
```

That's it.

Comment: with a variable "$button_title", How to set a title in js